# Removing dir contents from single file system in Python

Tags: python

The `rm` command allows you to do something like this:

```
rm -rf --one-file-system /path/to/dir/
```

And it will error out (skipping removal) if the contents of that dir have other file systems mounted in them.

Is there a module in Python that allows me to specify a similar behavior? If not, what would be the alternative to enforce such a constraint?

Comment: check here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4453602/how-to-find-the-mountpoint-a-file-resides-on

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no module that does this for you; you'll have to write it yourself.

But the `os` module provides everything you need to write it.*

First, [`os.walk`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.walk) can walk an entire directory tree. You can [`os.stat`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.stat) each directory and either skip those whose `st_dev` is different from the root's, or you can [`os.path.ismount`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.ismount) each directory and skip those that are true.

This is almost exactly what `rm` is doing under the covers, except that of course it's using [`fts`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fts.3.html) (or one of its predecessors, on older systems) rather than a Python function.

There are two tricky bits.

First, unlike `fts` and similar functions, `os.walk` doesn't stat the files (or, worse, it *does* stat the files, but doesn't give you the results), so you have to call `os.stat` explicitly on each `dirname`. (Or use a third-party module like [`scandir`](https://github.com/benhoyt/scandir), `betterwalk`, `py-fts`, etc.)

Second, you have to go top-down to prune the walk (in top-down mode, if you remove dirs from the `dirnames` argument, `walk` will not recurse into them), but you have to go bottom-up to remove the files before removing the directories. With APIs like `fts`, which allow both pre-visiting and post-visiting in the same traversal, this isn't a problem, but `os.walk` makes you choose one or the other.

But this should be enough for you to get started on this. If you get stuck, you can always ask a new question.

---

* Well, `os` and `os.path`.