# Find root of mapped volume (network-attached storage)

Tags: python, python-3.x, unix, path, volumes

I have a network-attached storage mapped to `/Volumes/Media`, and then I use the path

```
/Volumes/Media/some/path/
```

in my program.

I want to be able to determine the what part of the path is the mapped drive, and which is the rest. Something like

```
os.path.split_volume('/Volumes/Media/some/path/') == '/Volumes/Media', 'some/path'
```

I am currently on Mac OS X, but I image that the code will generally run in a Linux environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4453715/4237316

```
def split_on_mount_point(path):
    mount_point = os.path.abspath(path)
    while not os.path.ismount(mount_point):
        mount_point = os.path.dirname(mount_point)

    return mount_point, os.path.relpath(path, mount_point)
```